# Outputting to a text file issue

Tags: c#

I'm having issues writing to a text file.

```
Console.Write(position[i] + " ");
```

right under the for loop compiles no problem, but the one under Console.SetOut(sw);
says that the name i doesn't exist in the current context. Can anyone help me to get the application output to appear in a text file?

```
 static void solve(int k)
    {

        if (k == N) 
        {

            Console.Write("Solution: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)

                Console.Write(position[i] + " ");

            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
            FileStream fs = new FileStream("Test.txt", FileMode.Create);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
            Console.SetOut(sw);
            Console.WriteLine(position[i] + " "); 
            sw.Close();
            sum += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) // Generate ALL combinations
            {

                if (isSafe(k, i))
                {
                    position[k] = i;

                    solve(k + 1);
                }
```

Comment: wrap your for loop around {} properly for starters and second step thru that messy code

Answer (score 2):

Your `i` variable defined in scope of `for` loop. When you exit this scope variable is not available.

Use [block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664737%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to execute several operators in same scope:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
       Console.Write(position[i] + " ");

       Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
       FileStream fs = new FileStream("Test.txt", FileMode.Create);
       StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
       Console.SetOut(sw);
       Console.WriteLine(position[i] + " "); 
       sw.Close();
       sum += 1;
 }
```

BTW without block your code is equivalent to

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
     // i is available only withing this block
     Console.Write(position[i] + " ");
}      

// here i is not available
```

Also I suggest to use `using` statement with disposable objects, like streams. And you can use same stream here, so define it in wider scope, before `for` loop. E.g.

```
using(FileStream stream = new FileStream("Test.txt", FileMode.Create))
using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
{
    TextWriter standardOutput = Console.Out;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        Console.SetOut(standardOutput);       
        Console.WriteLine(position[i] + " ");
        Console.SetOut(writer);
        Console.WriteLine(position[i] + " ");
    }

    sum++; // instead of sum += 1
} // stream will be closed automatically
```

If you want to mirror console output to file, then I suggest you to use [TraceListeners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y5y10s7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or some logging framework. E.g.

```
Trace.Listeners.Clear();
Trace.Listeners.Add(new ConsoleTraceListener());
Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener("Test.txt"));
Trace.AutoFlush = true;

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)    
     Trace.WriteLine(position[i] + " ");
```

Comment: I tried the trace method and it seems to almost be working except that everytime it goes through the for loop it creates a new text file (96 text files) instead of storing all the data in one text file if that makes sense. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user3661876 you should move listeners adding out of loop, see my last example

Comment: Sorry having trouble adding code to comment http://pastebin.com/seKtQiJ9 and I have the listeners out of the loop?

Comment: @user3661876 do you have any outer loops? There is nothing in your code which will create several files